# Read only certain strings from file

Tags: c, file, random

I wanted to generate random names using `rand()` and linking each name to an integer (e.g. 1 if for Daniel, 2 for Sarah and so on). I wrote fuction `void random_name ()` and used `switch` to link each number `rand()` returned to a name, but now I want to do this using a file. How can I read from file only the line starting with 1 for example? Thank you:)

Comment: What you tried? Can you post?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just get a random number and then read that many lines from the file, take to content of the last read line as the actual name? In this case each line would only contain a name. `int rand = rand(); while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL && r) { r--; } // here line would contain the contents of the line at the random position` something like that.

Comment: To learn what's written at the beginning of the line you need to read the line.

Comment: @Cyclone I didn't think of that! It might be the easiest solution tbh.

Comment: @alk Isn't there a function to read only those line containing for example the string "abba", given "abba" as a parameter? (I remember reading something like that online much time ago)

Comment: How do expect this to work? To learn what is written on a book's page, you need to read the page, don't you?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. Perhaps it was to write and not read?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have a number and a name on each line you would have to read each line looking for the randomly generated number. One way to achive this would be something like this:

```
srand(time(0));
// random number between 1 and 10
int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
char line[128];
char name[64];
int number;
FILE* file = fopen("names.txt", "r");
if(file) {
    // loop while not EOF 
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) {
        // scan the line for a number and a name
        sscanf(line, "%d %s", &number, name);
        // if the number is equal to the random one break the loop
        if(number == r) {
            printf("random name is %s\n", name);
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

If you only have one name on each line and at least 10 different names, this would work:

```
srand(time(0));
int r = rand() % 10 + 1;
char line[128];
FILE* file = fopen("names.txt", "r");
if(file) {
    // loop while not EOF and r > 0, when r is 0 then we have
    // read r amount of lines from the file
    while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL && --r);
    printf("random name is %s\n", line);
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: Why "--r"? I'm sorry to bother you this much, but I'm really new to programming..

Comment: @SCoder: `r` is a countdown for the *n* numbered line. So the loop will stop when `r==0` or `fgets` fails, and in both cases the last line read will be shown.